# Workflow when building django project with git/github

Tags: python, django, git, github, mezzanine

I am developing a django project with several others. When I create the project, I have the virtualenv, `requirements.txt` and my django project in my directory. I commit the entire directory and upload to github. Another developer clones the project to his own machine. He created a new virtualenv with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. However, when he did `python manage.py runserver`, it gives him error saying something wrong with the configuration. I tried that with a plain new django project and the problem occurs. I just wonder what the right workflow would be when developing django projects with several developers.

[Update]
Sorry, I realized the problem only happens when I use django with the mezzanine framework. The error is

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be
empty.
```

Comment: what something `something wrong with the configuration`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Currently I am working on a mezzanine project and the error i got is "improperlyconfigured the secret keysetting-must not be empty". But I have encountered similar problems with a plain django project.

Comment: Basically after I clone the project and create a virtualenv, I cannot run python manage.py runserver successfully.

Comment: The problem seems quite clear: the settings file is missing the `SECRET_KEY`.

Comment: but then how come I don't see the error when I create the project the first time. I see this error only when I clone the project and try to runserver.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured out the problem is in `.gitignore`. Basically by default git ignores my database file and my local setting, which contains my secret key. Once I copied the local setting file to my local repo. I can run `python manage.py runserver` successfully. So to answer my original question, the proper workflow is to first clone the project from github. Then create a `localsetting.py` on your local and put the secret key in your `localsetting.py`. After that you do `mezzanine-project createdb`. Then you can run `python manage.py runserver` successfully.